# How to control the capitalization of month and day names returned by DateFormat?

Tags: java, date, internationalization

Here is a quick test program:

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    System.out.println("Months:");
    printDate( "MMMM", "en", date );
    printDate( "MMMM", "es", date );
    printDate( "MMMM", "fr", date );
    printDate( "MMMM", "de", date );

    System.out.println("Days:");
    printDate( "EEEE", "en", date );
    printDate( "EEEE", "es", date );
    printDate( "EEEE", "fr", date );
    printDate( "EEEE", "de", date );

}

public static void printDate( String format, String locale, Date date )
{
    System.out.println( locale + ": " + (new SimpleDateFormat( format, new Locale( locale ) )).format( date ) );
}
```

The output is:

`Months:
en: September
es: septiembre
fr: septembre
de: September
Days:
en: Monday
es: lunes
fr: lundi
de: Montag`

How can I control the capitalization of the names. For some reason the Spanish and French always seem to return names that start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not all languages share english capitalization rules. I guess you'd need to alter the data used by the API, but your non-english clients might not appreciate it...

[about.com on french capitalization](http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-capitalization.htm)

Comment: I think you are right. Another link with more details on which languages capitalize and which don't. http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Capitalization_of_month_names

Comment: Yeah but what about the first word of a sentence? _Lundi, j'ai travaillé._ is perfectly valid French, and it has a capital `L`.

Comment: Yeap, having the same problem when it is the first word.

Answer (score 8):

Capitalisation rules are different for different languages.  In French, month names [should not be capitalised](http://french.about.com/library/writing/bl-capitalization.htm).

Answer (score 5):

You may not want to change the capitalization -- different cultures capitalize different words (for example, in German you capitalize every noun, not just proper nouns).

Comment: It's not that I want to change the capitalization. It's that the client (who speaks neither language I'm implementing) **insists** I change the capitalization.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

> How can I control the capitalization of the names

You don’t. Different languages and different cultures have different rules about capitalization, punctuation, abbreviation, etc.

### `getDisplayName` — automatically localize

```
Month.from( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) )    // Get current month.
     .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )     // Localize automatically. Specify `Locale` to determine human language and cultural norms for translation.
```

> février

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )                  // Get current date as seen by people in a certain region (time zone).
    .getDayOfWeek()                                               // Get the day-of-week as a pre-defined `DayOfWeek` enum object.
    .getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH )
```

> lundi

## Localize

As others stated, you should not be forcing your own parochial (US English?) notions of capitalization. Use a decent date-time library, and let it automatically localize for you.

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

To work with a month, extract a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object. Ditto for day-of-week, [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).

Call `getDisplayName`. Pass a [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) for abbreviation. Pass a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such. Note that `Locale` has *nothing* to do with time zone.

```
Month m = today.getMonth() ;
String mNameQuébec = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ; 
String mNameGermany = m.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.GERMANY ) ;
```

…and…

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
String dowNameQuébec = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ; 
String dowNameGermany = dow.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.GERMANY ) ;
```

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).