# Java SimpleDateFormat.format(date) configuration

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, simpledateformat, zk

i am developing a Google-Calendar alike using Zk-Calendar i have a question about `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` here is some code

1). how to get the `day` and `month` in `first letter uppercase is this possible`?

here is the code i'm using so far.

```
private final SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
private void printDateTester() 
{
    final Locale VENEZUELA_LOCALE = new Locale("es","VE");
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println(locale.getDisplayCountry()+" "+locale.getCountry());//prints United States US
    System.out.println(VENEZUELA_LOCALE.getDisplayCountry()+" "+VENEZUELA_LOCALE.getCountry());//prints Venezuela VE
    final Calendar TODAY_US  = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
    final Calendar TODAY_VEN = Calendar.getInstance(VENEZUELA_LOCALE);
    System.out.println(dformat.format(TODAY_US.getTime())); //prints sábado 10-agosto-2013 11:07:55 AM  
    System.out.println(dformat.format(TODAY_VEN.getTime()));//prints sábado 10-agosto-2013 11:07:55 AM    
}
```

it prints something like `sabado 10-agosto-2013 09:42:24 AM in english something like saturday 10-august-2013` but i would like something like `Saturday 10-August-2013 09:42:24 AM` is this possible?

any ideas thanks a lot.

**UPDATE**

i have create 2 SimpleDateFormats 1 using `Locale.US` and 2 other using either `Venezuela Locale` and `Spain Locale` the `US` version prints in `Uppercase` but both `Venezuela and Spain` locales prints in `lowercase` but i need show the data in `Spanish` why is this??

```
final Locale VENEZUELA_LOCALE = new Locale("es","VE");
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();        
final SimpleDateFormat dformatI  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a",VENEZUELA_LOCALE);        
final SimpleDateFormat dformatII = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a",Locale.US);        

Locale: Venezuela VE
print: domingo 11-agosto-2013 09:24:25 AM
Locale: United States US
print: Sunday 11-August-2013 09:24:25 AM
```

Comment: Why you are using clazz.dformat.format(TODAY.getTime()? Shouldn't it be dformat.format(TODAY.getTime()?

Comment: yes a typing mistake thanks a lot.

Comment: which locale are u using? at my machine it prints everything upper case?

Comment: hello Christian please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting Locale in DateTime format object:

```
    private final SimpleDateFormat dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd-MMMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a",Locale.US);
```

Not all languages are following US standard (Capitalized day and month names). Therefore what output value java **DateTimeFormat** is giving was expected.

You could find this interesting discussion in the following questions

[How to control the capitalization of month and day names returned by DateFormat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750/how-to-control-the-capitalization-of-month-and-day-names-returned-by-dateformat)

Comment: hello Shamim i have create 2 SimpleDateFormats one using Locale.US and other using Venezuela,Spain locales the US locale prints in Uppercase exactly as i want to but both Venezuela and Spain prints in lowercase with is this? i need print it in spanish....

Comment: i think so... thanks a lot... there is nothing i could do.. hehe.