# Java's MessageFormat Not Localizing Portuguese Months in Dates in Lowercase

Tags: java, date, localization, messageformat

The month names start with an uppercase letter instead of lowercase, [as they should](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Capitalization_of_Wiktionary_pages#Capitalization_of_month_names).

Some sample code I ran on my local machine:

```
  Locale portugal = new Locale("pt");
  Locale brazil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
  Locale france = new Locale("fr", "FR");

  Object[] params = new Object[] { new Date() };
  String pattern = "Today is {0,date,long}!";

  MessageFormat ptFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern, portugal);
  MessageFormat brFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern, brazil);
  MessageFormat frFormat = new MessageFormat(pattern, france);

  StringBuffer ptResult = ptFormat.format(params, new StringBuffer(), new FieldPosition(0));
  StringBuffer brResult = brFormat.format(params, new StringBuffer(), new FieldPosition(0));
  StringBuffer frResult = frFormat.format(params, new StringBuffer(), null);

  System.out.println("Portugal result: " + ptResult.toString());
  System.out.println("Brazil result: " + brResult.toString());
  System.out.println("France result: " + frResult.toString());
```

And this is what I got:

```
Portugal result: Today is 10 de Julho de 2018!
Brazil result: Today is 10 de Julho de 2018!
France result: Today is 10 juillet 2018!
```

So the French is correct, but for some reason the two Portuguese variants are not.

Even weirder, I tried adding the exact same code as an [IDEAONE snippet](https://ideone.com/s2sjS2), and it wouldn't localize at all.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: On my Java 9 I get the result you say you want: `11 de julho de 2018`, etc. On my Java 8 I get the capitalized month that you don’t want. On Java 8 you can get your desired lower case if you define the system property `java.locale.providers` as `CLDR,COMPAT` (or some other combination where CLDR comes before COMPAT or JRE).

Comment: It would seem to me that you understood everything correctly, but those defining Portuguese month names for Java misunderstood.

Comment: Does that work for Java 7 as well?

Comment: From [the documentation of `LocaleServiceProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html): “Starting from JDK8, the search order of locale sensitive services can be configured by using the "java.locale.providers" system property.” So apparently not. You can try if you want to be sure.

Comment: @DmitriV Add a tag on your Question for which version of Java you are using.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

- Different implementations of Java may vary in their rules for localization.
- Different versions of an implementation of Java may vary in their rules for localization.

For the Oracle JDK & OpenJDK projects, version 9 and later switched between its own set of rules and the set of rules defined by the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)). See [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8008577) and see [OpenJDK JEP 252](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/252).

Run this code:

```
Month.JULY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , new Locale( "pt" ) )
```

In Java 8, Oracle JDK, by default using its **own localization rules**, we get initial-cap.

> Julho

In Java 10, Oracle JDK, by default **using Unicode CLDR** rules, we get lowercase.

> julho

In Java 10, Oracle JDK after setting the VM option `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,SPI` to revert to legacy behavior rather than using Unicode CLDR, we get initial-cap.

> Julho

## Details

- The formatting rules defined by cultural norms may vary by [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) implementation and version.
- The [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) in **IdeOne.com refuses to localize**. Only US English. [See proof](https://www.ideone.com/VE5oQo).
- You are using the wrong classes. **Use *java.time*** for all date-time handling.

Code.

```
ZonedDateTime       // Use modern class for a moment seen from a particular time zone.
.now()              // Capture the current moment, using the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to specify a zone explicitly.
.format(            // Generate a `String` representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( new Locale( "pt" , "BR" ) ) 
)                   // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 11 de julho de 2018 17:57:36 NZST

## Cultural norms

Deciding an issue such as capitalization of a month name depends on a culture’s norms. Of course, those norms can vary, and reasonable people can disagree.

But at some point, decisions have to be made. A Java implementation must have a set of rules for making these localization rules.

### Unicode CLDR

Perhaps you are using Java 8 or earlier. My code in this Answer was produced with Java 10.

One important difference is that as of Java 9, for the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK projects, the default source of [localization rules changed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8008577) to using the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)). In Java 8 and earlier, each JVM provided their own set of rules.

Also, note that the Unicode CLDR is updated from time-to-time, and some rules may change.

So, you may well see different results for localization depending on which version of Java is in use, and on which implementation of Java is in use.

### Context of presentation

Perhaps the issue here is one of context. In some cultures, the formatting rules such as capitalization of a month name vary by whether the month is being presented alone or embedded within a date.

Let’s try translate.Google.com:

- `July` yields `Julho`
- `Early in the month of July` yields `no início do mês de julho`
- `12th of July, 2018` yields `12 de julho de 2018`

So Google seems to vary by context, but I am not certain what is going on with that first case being initial-cap.

This context can be indicated by the use of the [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) enum used in [`Month::getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method. That enum offers `…STANDALONE` variations.

```
Month.JULY.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL , 
    new Locale( "pt" )
)
```

> julho

```
Month.JULY.getDisplayName(
    TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE , 
    new Locale( "pt" )
)
```

> julho

So no, context seems to not be an issue here when using Java 10.

## java.time

You are using the troublesome old classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Instead of `java.util.Date`, use `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC. The modern `Instant` class uses a finer resolution of nanoseconds instead of milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-07-11T05:57:36.446917Z

Adjust from UTC to the time zone where the people of that region use a particular wall-clock time you desire. Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. Time zone is completely orthogonal to locale. One relates to the content of the moment, the other affects only the localization used in generating a String to represent that content. You could, for example, use a Japan time zone with a Portuguese locale.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now, we want to generate strings representing that moment. First, generate a `String` in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Generate ISO 8601 format string.
```

> 2018-07-11T17:57:36.446917+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]

You want to localize the generated `String` objects. Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) to control the formatting of the `String` to be generated. Specify a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to control how long or abbreviated.

```
Locale l_pt = new Locale( "pt" ) ;
Locale l_ptBR = new Locale( "pt" , "BR" ) ;
Locale l_FR = Locale.FRANCE ;

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ) ;

String output_pt = zdt.format( f.withLocale( l_pt ) ) ;
String output_ptBR = zdt.format( f.withLocale( l_ptBR ) ) ;
String output_FR = zdt.format( f.withLocale( l_FR ) ) ;
```

> quarta-feira, 11 de julho de 2018 17:57:36 Horário Padrão da Nova Zelândia
>
> quarta-feira, 11 de julho de 2018 17:57:36 Horário Padrão da Nova Zelândia
>
> mercredi 11 juillet 2018 à 17:57:36 heure normale de la Nouvelle-Zélande

For fun, let’s try [`FormatStyle.LONG`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#LONG) instead of `FULL`.

> 11 de julho de 2018 17:57:36 NZST
>
> 11 de julho de 2018 17:57:36 NZST
>
> 11 juillet 2018 à 17:57:36 NZSTe

## IdeOne refuses to localize

I enjoy using IdeOne.com to demo Java code. Unfortunately, its JVM refuses to use any `Locale` except US English. So, no go for the code above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## A brief history of time

Responding to comments on this Answer…

Timeline:

- [Sun Microsystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) launches [Java 1.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history) with some date-time classes (`java.util.Date` etc.) donated by IBM/[Taligent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taligent). Unfortunately, they are poorly-designed and flawed, confusing and troublesome.
- Sun adds more classes in Java 1.1 (`java.util.Calendar` etc.) in an attempt to improve the date-time handling. But these too turn out to be poorly-designed and confusing, not a real improvement.
- Years later, a man [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen) founds the *Joda-Time* project, to make a comprehensive sophisticated date-time handling library, a first in the IT industry afaik. Huge success. One of the most popular Java libraries, added routinely to many developers’ projects.
- Sun, then Oracle, and the [JCP community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process) finally recognize that the old date-time classes shipped with the earliest versions of Java are not adequate. This recognition opens the door for that same Stephen Colebourne to launch [JSR 310](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983209), a specification for an all-new date-time API for inclusion as part of the Java platform. This project is based on concepts from Joda-Time, but is an entirely new rewrite. The new rewrite builds on the experience of having created Joda-Time, asking “If we knew then what we know now, how would we have designed Joda-Time?”.
- The implementation of JSR 310 is built as the *java.time* package to be included with the then-upcoming Java 8.
- To ensure wider acceptance of the *java.time* API, Stephen Colebourne launches the open-source [*ThreeTen-Backport*](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, mimicking nearly the same API as in *java.time* but capable of running on Java 6 and Java 7. Not quite all of the *java.time* functionality, but most of it. The goal is to enable a developer on earlier Java to start using the API. Then when moving to later versions of Java they need do little more than change their `import` statements from `org.threeten.bp.*` to `java.time.*`.
- With Java 8 successfully shipping, Stephen Colebourne et al. shift the Joda-Time project into maintenance-mode, still actively updated with [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tz_database) changes and bug fixes, but no further feature work to be done. They advise migration away from Joda-Time and on to the *java.time* classes.
- Stephen Colebourne also launches the open-source [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project to work on additional features that may or may not eventually be submitted to later versions of JSR 310 (to become additional *java.time* classes). Meanwhile, these extra features, extensions to the *java.time* functionality, are provided as a library to the public for those developers who find them useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for all that info. We do import the Joda time 2.2 JAR, but I tried using it and still get the same result:
`Locale portugal = new Locale("pt");`
`LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();` 
`DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.longDate();` 
`System.out.println("Portugal v2: " + formatter.withLocale(portugal).print(now));`

Result: `Portugal v2: 11 de Julho de 2018`

Shouldn't this work since now I'm using the java.time classes?

Comment: Wanted to add, I'm on 1.7 Java, so I can't use Java 8 or later classes directly.

Comment: @DmitriV **Carefully re-read** the *About java.time* section of my Answer. Replace *Joda-Time* with *ThreeTen-Backport* for Java 6 and Java 7. The API is nearly identical to the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. When you eventually move to Java 8 or later, you’ll need do little more than change your `import` statements.

Comment: Just so I understand where the issue lies here, is it with some JRE classes? And using ThreeTenBP project avoids using those classes while Joda-Time does not?

Comment: @DmitriV I added a "A brief history of time" section that may clarify things for you.

Comment: I've switched to using the threeten classes, and it's still the same behaviour: `System.out.println("Portugal v3: " + LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(new Locale("pt", "PT"))));` and I still get the exact same result: `=> Portugal v3: 12 de Julho de 2018`

Comment: I even dug up your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66750/how-to-control-the-capitalization-of-month-and-day-names-returned-by-dateformat) and tried doing `System.out.println("month only: " + Month.from(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Auckland"))).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, new Locale("pt", "PT")));` and still get `Julho`. Switching to using `FULL_STANDALONE` gave the same result.

Comment: @DmitriV What is wrong with the output as you quoted in your last 2 comments? Looks correct to me (not that I speak Portuguese). [Google says](https://translate.google.com/#en/pt/July) that *July* in English is *Julho* in Portuguese. Is your issue simply that you claim the cultural norm in Portuguese is for a month name to be in lowercase? If so, apparently the people editing the [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org) disagree with you. Java 9 and later [switched to using CLDR by default](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html#JDK-8008577) for localizing.

Comment: @DmitriV This uppercase-lowercase problem turns out to be confusing but interesting. I'm updating my Answer now. I suspect the difference between what you and I are seeing is due to the rules of cultural norms used in formatting being changed. Are you using Java before or after 9? As of 9, Unicode CLDR rules are used by default, at list in the Oracle JDK and OpenJDK projects. I am using Java 10, the Oracle JDK implementation for macOS.