# How to get Full Day name (in uppercase) through Elastic Search query?

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, opensearch

I want the Day name of `record_created_at` here, as `MONDAY`, `TUESDAY`, ... Format

I tried with the below, i'm getting the only first 3 letters and that too in Title case,

```json
{
    "date_histogram": {
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "field": "record_created_at",
        "format": "E"
    }
}
```

How can i can get full day name in Upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query and it will give you the full day names in aggregation.
you can refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html#date-format-pattern) document.

```json
{
    "date_histogram": {
        "calendar_interval": "day",
        "field": "record_created_at",
        "format": "EEEE"
    }
}
```

You can not change the capitalization and you can done once getting response from Elasticsearch. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66784/5489276) answer as Elasticsearch internally use DateTimeFormatter for formatting.